# How to configure Streaming on Starbound

Tags: starbound, streaming

In Starbound, when you click on F6 you can open a menu to start a streming on Twitch.

[image]

And how it says, you have to configure the "streamingvideo.config" file. This file contains this code inside:

```
{
  "startAtLoad" : false,
  "kind" : "twitch",
  "targetFps" : 30,
  "verticalFlip" : true,
  "caCertPath" : ".\\curl-ca-bundle.crt",
  "dllLoadPath" : ".",
  "username" : "",
  "password" : "",
  "audioEnabled" : true,
  "tracing" : false,
  "traceFile" : ".\\twitch.log",
  "refreshTimer" : 30.0
}
```

But i don't know how to configure it. the "only" fields that I changed are "username" and "password" that I put my account on twitch.

Then I push the Start button, but doesn't works given the error that can be seen on image.

How can I Configure it to make it work?

Comment: Forget about those ingame functions for streaming. They often deliver poor quality and are not really optimized. use Open Broadcaster instead, it works better and has better quality.

Comment: Quite a few of us have looked into this so far.. We have come to the conclusion that this part of the game is still a WIP and not usable at this time... This may have changed in last night's patch though.

Comment: Seconding Open Broadcaster Software. Worked for me with game capture and no further questions asked. Although it produced noticeable FPS damage when trying to record Starbound. It probably has more to do with the game being unoptimised yet and my own computer being a bit overloaded at the time.

Answer (score 5):

The in-game streaming option are being developed at the current stage of the game. However, programs such as OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) are effective for recording such things quite well, with a much wider assortment of options.

Answer (score -1):

If the streaming implementation worked, you would also need your streaming key, which you can find at

http://www.twitch.tv/*/dashboard/streamkey

replace the asterisk with whatever username you're logged in with, and wish to stream on. Looking at that config type file, I'm not sure where you'd input it, but I do know that you need the key.

Comment: You don't need a stream key, it's just the most common way to do it.